# macOS files 0 KB in size, what is corrupting them?

Tags: macos, finder, file-corruption, macos-mojave

Today I searched for files that were 0 KB in size after finding one by accident.

I found 905 files that were 0 KB; everything from photos and sounds to useless cache.db files.

The oldest zeroed file was 18-Aug-1995. The newest file was 10-Dec-2018

[image]

**Try the search in the Finder yourself. How many files have you lost?** Any idea how/why?

My disk reports it is fine in Disk Utility.

Additional Research - numbers of files and documents zeroed:

- Mac Pro on Sierra - 49,464
- Son's MBP Retina on Mojave - 319
- Daughter's MBP Retina on Sierra - 101
- Friend ADH Mac on Mojave - 190
- Friend SMW Mac on High Sierra - 1,840
- Work web server Snow Leopard - 514
- Work server High Sierra - 181

Condition notes

- Some disks are encrypted, some are external, some are internal, some are RAID, some are SSD, some are spinning disks.
- document file dates range from 1995 to today
- impacted regular documents will not open and result in 'The file “nameOfFile” could not be opened because it is empty.'
- Document and File types include .txt, .docx, .pictClipping, .JPG, .PDF, .numbers, .xls, .plist, .html, .h, .c, .m, .swift, .zip, .vcf, .log, .roll, .webloc, .vmsd, .aspx
- zeroed file locations can be directly in Finder or within packages or bundles

Comment: Assuming that they are "corrupted" is a bit of a stretch. Many programs create placeholders for files or they could be used for indication configuration or meant to be deleted after some time. If this is happening to files you are actually wanting to use or are stopping programs from working then it would be a concern but there simply being some files that are 0 bytes is not a sign of something nefarious.

Comment: @Mokubai  I found this when I tried to open up a "Web Location" file ".webloc". The file is next to a PDF in the same folder. The PDF is intact.  This is the same story for multiple Xcode project folders of mine, one or two files zero, rest are fine. Lost 58 source code files across several projects in my project folder. Still assessing damage. If not corrupted, what to call that?

Comment: @WilliamCerniuk Please don't spam the comments with updates that aren't replies to other users' comments. Please edit your original Question post to contain the additional findings, and delete the spurious comments.

Comment: I'm a longtime Mac user and I always migrate my entire system when I upgrade, so my main MBP has almost 3 decades of cruft on it. I have over 600 zero-length files, but they all seem "intentional": lock files, log files that some daemon created but apparently never needed to log any actual log messages to, "turd files" that git and other source code control systems drop into directories to help them track changes, empty temp files left behind when some app upgrade caused a sqlite database migration, and things like that. Nothing attributable to disk/filesystem corruption.

Comment: Also note that if you have files around from the classic Mac OS days, they may have empty data forks because they store all their data in the resource fork, so some Unix-layer tools in modern macOS that only look at the data fork would call them zero-length when they actually aren't.

Comment: @Spiff Under macOS X Mojave a resource fork on a file is still counted in the byte count of the file in the Finder. I verified with an old Finder ".textclipping". A spot check on the files and documents of 0 KB show neither "data fork" nor "resource fork".  Do you have any documents in the 600 zero length files you found that have resource forks that are not counted?

Comment: @spiff as shown in the image, some could be sloppy programmer left-behinds but the majority had data. Of the 900+ 0 KB files in my storage device, 195 were Finder "Text Clippings", all now empty. Creation dates ranging from 2008 to 2018.